# Equivalent to IF NOT EXISTS in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, exists

Following statement works in MSSQL:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[FK_StationObjectsID]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[Attendance]'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Attendance ADD CONSTRAINT FK_StationObjectsID FOREIGN KEY (StationObjectsID) REFERENCES stationobjects (stationobjectsid)
END
```

In Oracle I tried:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FK_STATIONOBJECTSID' AND TABLE_NAME = 'ATTENDANCE') THEN
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Attendance ADD CONSTRAINT FK_StationObjectsID FOREIGN KEY (StationObjectsID) REFERENCES stationobjects (stationobjectsid);
END;
```

but its giving me an error PLS-00103 "Encountered the symbol 'ALTER'..."

Comment: Try `execute immediate 'alter . . .'`

Comment: You need a PL/SQL block with dynamic SQL for that

Comment: Thanks GurV, now getting another error that the foreign key already exists. Seems like there is anything wrong with the IF. When executing the SELECT its returning one row, but its still trying to execute the ALTER...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use execute immediate to fire ddl inside PLSQL block:

```
IF <condition> THEN 
    Execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE . . .';
END if;
```

Closest that come to not exists is a method given by Tom Kyte [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3069487275935)

```
begin
  for i in (select count(*) cnt from dual 
            where not exists (
                SELECT *
                FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS 
                WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FK_STATIONOBJECTSID' 
                AND TABLE_NAME = 'ATTENDANCE'
            )) loop
            if (i.cnt = 1) then
              execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE Attendance ADD CONSTRAINT FK_StationObjectsID FOREIGN KEY (StationObjectsID) REFERENCES stationobjects (stationobjectsid)';
            end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Simpler method would be:

```
declare
  n int := 0;
begin
  select count(*) into n
  from user_constraints
  where constraint_name = 'FK_STATIONOBJECTSID'
  and table_name = 'ATTENDANCE';
  if n = 0 then
    execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE Attendance ADD CONSTRAINT FK_StationObjectsID FOREIGN KEY (StationObjectsID) REFERENCES stationobjects (stationobjectsid)';
  end if;
end;
/
```

See 
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37362/why-cant-we-write-ddl-statement-directly-into-the-pl-sql-block

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`EXISTS`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/EXISTS-Condition.htm#SQLRF52167) in a SQL query, but not in a PLSQL condition the way you tried.

You may need the following:

```
declare
    vCheck number;
begin
    select count(1)
    into vCheck
    from user_constraints
    where constraint_name = 'FK_STATIONOBJECTSID'
      and table_name = 'ATTENDANCE';
    --
    if vCheck = 0 then
        execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE Attendance ADD CONSTRAINT FK_StationObjectsID FOREIGN KEY (StationObjectsID) REFERENCES stationobjects (stationobjectsid)';
    end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, possibly not the best solution though:

```
DECLARE
  foreign_key_exists number := 0;  
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO foreign_key_exists FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE upper(CONSTRAINT_NAME) = upper('FK_StationObjectsID') AND upper(TABLE_NAME) = upper('Attendance');
  IF (foreign_key_exists = 0) 
    THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE Attendance ADD CONSTRAINT FK_StationObjectsID FOREIGN KEY (StationObjectsID) REFERENCES stationobjects (stationobjectsid)';
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

How about executing the DDL, and ignoring any "foreign key already exists" error.

Not elegant, but not dependent on the key name not changing.